# Conda pack not placing environment in correct path

Tags: python, windows, anaconda, conda, conda-pack

I am using conda pack on a windows computer. Using `conda pack -n env_name -o \path\env_name.tar.gz` does not place the tar file in the correct path. Does anyone have experience with this issue?

For image 1 I tried packing the environment from the explicit environment itself

[image]

For image 2 I tried packing the environment from the base

[image]

Comment: Please give a full string example of the command you use, where you expect it to output to, and where it does output to.

Comment: @merv I added two images to the main comment of the the commands I attempted to use. Both of which did not place the tar file in any location.